# Listing most recent files whose total sizes are about a certain value

Tags: linux

I would like to copy the most recent files in a directory to another directory such that the total sizes of the files I would like to copy should be 10gb, let say.

I know that I can list the most recent 10 files with a certain amount of size like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +100M -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Shal | head
```

But, is there any way to find the most recent files whose total sizes are about 10gb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. `find` has a `printf` action that allows you to output only the information you are interested in. In your case, that would be a timestamp (e.g. last modification time), the file size, and the name of the file. You can then sort the output according to the timestamp, and use `awk` to sum the file sizes and output the file names up to a certain limit:

```
find "$some_directory" -printf "%T@ %s %p\n" | sort -nr \
    | awk '{ a = a + $2; if (a > 10000) { print a; exit; }; print $3; }'
```

Adjust the limit according to your needs, and remove `print a` if you are not interested in the result. If you want to include the file that pushes the sum over the limit, replace `print a` with `print $3`.

Comment: but my problem is to find maximum number of recent files such that when we sum up their sizes, it is less than 10gb. It is not file specific, let say we have 1000 files in the directory. The last 10 file has total of 11gb and the last 9 file has 9.8gb. I want the last 9 file.

Comment: Only nit would be `"$some_directory"`, in case the user blindly tries on, e.g. `My Documents` (or some other such nonsense...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are right, of course, but I only used that as a meta-variable. Maybe I should have said `$foo`.

Comment: The quoting was the 'nit' (and I mean small potatoes and something anybody should catch if they have issue), but being a good teacher, you always want to show the correct use to avoid possible *word-splitting*. Personally I like `"$some_directory"` or `"$path"` just fine, `"$foo"` would lose the path connotation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Done.